# Why can't i import pygame on anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, anaconda

i'm trying import pygame on anaconda. I have try it by open spyder, type code as follows:

```
import pygame
```

Then something happens as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call lasat):
file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I have done some research on google about this. i think it has something to do with this link: https://anaconda.org/CogSci/pygame.
I have download file on this link. but i don't know what to do about it.

Why can't i import pygame? How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about my last answer. I got what you're doing wrong. The modules/packages installations must happen in a cmd, not from the python shell. You're trying to install it from the python shell directly. Just open a cmd window and type

```
conda install pygame
```

and it should work.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work gives the following error : PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pygame

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 6):

The command listed earlier:

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

will install pygame 1.9.2a0 which is an older package. I was able to find 1.9.5 at this channel:

```
conda install -c delichon pygame
```

But, since that version might be old by the time you read this, you might be better off going to https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo and searching for pygame there. That way you'll be able to see which versions are available on which channel (like cogsci or delichon).

Answer (score 2):

1. [Activate your environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

   ```
   conda activate myenv
   ```
2. [Install Pygame in Conda](https://anaconda.org/cogsci/pygame)

   ```
   conda install -c cogsci pygame
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the start menu > anaconda3 > anaconda prompt
in there type `pip install pygame`

I tried many solutions and this was the only one that worked for me.